# Poor npm install performance in dev container with multiple node_modules directory

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I have the following `devcontainer.json` file which I've setup [following an example on the VSCode website here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance?WT.mc_id=javascript-14373-yolasors#_use-a-targeted-named-volume).

Inside my project, I have three `package.json` files, which install `node_modules` within the root, `/docs` and `/storybook` directories. My container starts just fine, and the root installation job runs very quickly, however when I run `npm install` within the dev container for any sub directories it hangs for a *very* long time, and often never completes due to a timeout.

This is what my `devcontainer.json` file looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "Node.js",
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": {"VARIANT": "20-bullseye"}
  },
  "mounts": [
    "source=${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}-node_modules,target=${containerWorkspaceFolder}/node_modules,type=volume",
    "source=${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}-storybook-node_modules,target=${containerWorkspaceFolder}/storybook/node_modules,type=volume",
    "source=${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}-docs-node_modules,target=${containerWorkspaceFolder}/docs/node_modules,type=volume"
  ],
  "forwardPorts": [3000]
}
```

And here's my `Dockerfile`

```
ARG VARIANT="20-bullseye"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:1-${VARIANT}

USER root
```

As you can see I've tried to mount each `node_modules` directory as a volume to speed the process up [outlined here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance?WT.mc_id=javascript-14373-yolasors#_use-a-targeted-named-volume), but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is there something I'm missing with my setup here? Do these volumes need to be provided with a unique id somehow, or something? Any help would be appreciated!